# Eclipse doesn't find my static libraries

Tags: eclipse, g++, static-libraries, eclipse-cdt

I want to use SRILM package in my project. I've compiled SRILM successfully and now there are static libraries in ~/srilm/lib/i686-ubuntu
I created a c++ project in eclipse and added libdstruct.a to libraries and set its path as directory for searching libraries. But eclipse can't find my library!
Following code is the output when I click on build project button in eclipse. As you see g++ says cannot find -llibdstruct

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project test ****

make all 
Building file: ../src/test.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/test.d" -MT"src/test.d" -o"src/test.o" "../src/test.c"
Finished building: ../src/test.c

Building target: test
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc -L/home/atp/srilm/lib/i686-ubuntu -o"test"  ./src/test.o   -llibdstruct
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibdstruct
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu. I'm sure about paths and file permissions are totally 777.

Comment: OK I myself found the reason of this problem. I should've use -ldstrust instead of -llibdstruct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibdstruct

When you pass `-llibdstruct` flag to the linker, you are asking it to look for a file called `liblibdstruct.a` . There is no such file, so the linker rightfully complains.

The file you *actually* want is called `libdstruct.a`, and the correct flag to pass is `-ldstruct`.

Comment: Yes thank you. I knew that I should remove .a but I didn't know that lib should be removed too.